# Calculating the sum of values in a list of tuples in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having two tuples in a list. For example: `[("A",100,2),("B",50,3)]`. I need to multiply the second and third elements of each and every tuple, sum the totals and show it. For example:

`100* 2 = 200` (add this to a variable),
 `50* 3 = 150` (add this to the same variable),
 Grant total = `350` (I want to display only this).

If any one can suggest me a solution for this it would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foldl (\a (x, y, z) -> a + y*z) 0 [("A", 100, 2), ("B", 50, 3)]`

This expands to: ((0 + 100 * 2) + 50 * 3)

Comment: -1 yet another full solution with no explanation.  I'm looking for people who will give guidance rather than a cut-and-paste-able answer; or if a full answer is given at least some insight into how you arrived at it.

Answer (score 13):

```
λ> sum $ map (\(_,y,z) -> y*z ) [("A",100,2),("B",50,3)]
350
```

**UPD:** trying to add some explanation

So, we have a tuple `("A",100,2)`. We need to get product of second and third element? With [anonymous function](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Anonymous_function).

```
λ> (\(x,y,z) -> y*z) ("A",100,2)
200
```

X is unusable here, so we can pass it

```
λ> (\(_,y,z) -> y*z) ("A",100,2)
200
```

Then we should apply that function to list of such tuples with [map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:map).

```
λ> map (\(_,y,z) -> y*z) [("A",100,2),("B",50,3)]
[200,150]
```

And last thing is finding sum of `[Int]` with [sum](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:sum).

```
λ> sum (map (\(_,y,z) -> y*z) [("A",100,2),("B",50,3)])
350
```

We can use `$`(function application) instead of parentheses.

```
λ> sum $ map (\(_,y,z) -> y*z) [("A",100,2),("B",50,3)]
350
```

Done.

Comment: Actually, it's hard to decide what should be explained. Answer is updated.

Comment: Yeah, for these simple questions that's true.  For questions like these, I also support guidance rather than a full solution: a hint, get the OP started instead of solving his problem for him.  Anyway, +1 :-)

Answer (score 9):

Using a list comprehension:

```
*Main> let tuples = [("A",100,2),("B",50,3)]
*Main> sum [x*y | (_,x,y) <- tuples]
350
```

Comment: Is using a list comprehension better then anything else, or you just suggest another way to generate the answer?

Comment: @dmitry.malikov: I think it's slightly easier to read, but other than that it should be equivalent to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.List (foldl')
sum_tuple_products = (foldl' (+) 0) . map (\(_, y, z) -> y * z)
```

You can look at this code this way: `map` first transforms the list of tuples `(x, y, z)` into a list of products `y * z`, then `foldl'` adds all the elements of that list.

```
*Main> sum_tuple_products [("a", 100, 2), ("B", 50, 3)]
350
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doit = foldr (\(_,b,c) acc -> b*c + acc) 0
```